# how to get websocket response with spring+stomp+sockjs

Tags: java, spring, stomp, sockjs

I use spring+stomp to broadcast a message to websocket client, but how can I know the result is success? I use the setSendTimeout method and catch Exception to detect whether the convertAndSend is success, but it doesn't work!
java code

```
@Resource
private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

@RequestMapping("/test")
public String test() {
    simpMessagingTemplate.setSendTimeout(1);
    String result;
    try {
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/test", "haha");
        result = "success!";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = "failed! \n" + e.toString();
    }
    return result;

}
```

js code

```
<script src="/lib/websocket/sockjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/websocket/stomp.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = new SockJS("/kefu");
  var client = Stomp.over(socket);
  client.debug = function (str) {
  };

  client.connect(
          {},
          function () {
            client.subscribe('/topic/test', function(msg) {
              console.log(msg);
            });
          },
          function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
  );

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

WebSockets is an abstract implementation of TCP over HTTP. TCP is reliable and guarantees delivery of packets to the recipient. Thus you don't need to worry about delivery from your application Controller to Front end Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!     After connection is disconnect and I didn't detect it, then I invoke the convertAndSend method, I fail to know whether  the client received my message!